# CDbException in www version of site with yii1.x and mssql

Tags: sql-server, yii1.x

I am new to `yii` and have a site built in `yii 1.1.x` with 2 `MSSQL2014` dbs one local and one residing in a remote server. I have used standard `yii` connection string in `main.php` as below:

```
'db'=>array(
'class'=>'CDbConnection',
'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server = '.$dbServer_t.'; Database = '.$dbName_t.'',
'username' => $dbUser_t,
'password' => $dbPass_t,
'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

The site seems to work fine with domain name `mydomain.com` but when running as `www.mydomain.com` the site is showing the following error

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[28000]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
>   user 'xxxxxx'.

I have checked separately in a test file outside `yii` directory with simple connection string for `MSSQL` and its working fine with both www and non www version. So it appears definitely somehow the issue is with `yii` and somehow its restricting db connection for www version.

Can anyone please help how to fix that?

Comment: `$dbServer_t` is it a domain name? if it is then try using an ip instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
No, I have already used $dbServer_t = IP of the server where the db resides